Why is req.body empty when posting form in quiz.ejs
app.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path=require('path');
const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
async function main(){
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/quizApp');
    console.log('db is connected');
}
main();
// Middleware
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'/views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', indexRoutes);

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


routes/index.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Quiz = require('../models/quiz');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const quizzes = await Quiz.find({});
    res.render('quiz', { quizzes });
});

router.post('/submit', async (req, res) => {
    const answers = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    let score = 0;
    const quizzes = await Quiz.find({});
    quizzes.forEach(quiz => {
        if (answers[quiz._id] === quiz.answer) {
            score++;
        }
    });
    res.render('result', { score, total: quizzes.length });
});

module.exports = router;


quiz.ejs
<form id="quizForm" action="http://localhost:3000/submit" method="post">
  <% quizzes.forEach((quiz, index) => { %>
  <div
    class="question-container"
    id="question-<%= index %>"
    style="display: none"
  >
    <p class="lead"><%= quiz.question %></p>
    <% quiz.options.forEach(option => { %>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="<%= 'question' + index + option %>"
        name="<%= quiz._id %>"
        value="<%= option %>"
        class="custom-control-input"
        onclick="checkAnswer('<%= quiz.answer %>', this)"
      />
      <label
        class="custom-control-label"
        for="<%= 'question' + index + option %>"
        ><%= option %></label
      >
    </div>
    <% }) %>
  </div>
  <% }) %>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary"
    id="prevBtn"
    onclick="changeQuestion(-1)"
    disabled
  >
    Previous
  </button>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-secondary"
    id="nextBtn"
    onclick="changeQuestion(1)"
    style="display: none"
  >
    Next
  </button>
  <button
    type="submit"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    id="submitBtn"
    style="display: none"
  >
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
<script>
  const questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question-container");
  let currentQuestionIndex = 0;

  function showQuestion(index) {
    questions.forEach((question, i) => {
      question.style.display = i === index ? "block" : "none";
    });
    document.getElementById("questionNumber").textContent =
      `${index + 1}/${questions.length}`;
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").disabled = index === 0;
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display =
      index === questions.length - 1 ? "none" : "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").style.display =
      index === questions.length - 1 ? "inline-block" : "none";
  }

  function changeQuestion(direction) {
    currentQuestionIndex += direction;
    showQuestion(currentQuestionIndex);
  }

  function checkAnswer(correctAnswer, selectedOption) {
    const questionContainer = selectedOption.closest(".question-container");
    const options = questionContainer.querySelectorAll(".custom-control-input");
    options.forEach((option) => {
      const label = questionContainer.querySelector(
        `label[for="${option.id}"]`,
      );
      if (option.value === correctAnswer) {
        label.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else if (option.checked) {
        label.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      option.disabled = true;
    });
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline-block";
  }

  // Initial display of the first question
  showQuestion(currentQuestionIndex);
</script>

Quiz model Schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const quizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
    options: [String],
    answer: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema);

Problem
In quiz.ejs why form give me empty object in console I proper give name and value of input after submit the form and goes to the submit router I mention in above code and I console.log(req.body) it give me a empty object. I make a quiz app website and when i give the all the answers of the questions and final submit then it not show the score it and  when i saw all my code then I see req,body give me empty object why i also use the middlewares to parse the post then why it give me empty object

Did you get this db is connected at console?What specific error you are getting?

How does your quiz model looks?

yes, db is connected and now, i mention the quiz model schema

most likely you're changing values/form with javascript functions checkAnswer and changeQuestion.. you might include them

How bro can I also include the javascript function of checkanswer and change question and then you tell me where am i wrong and how i improve this

Open your browser's dev-tools Network panel and inspect the POST request. It should show you what the body / payload looks like. If that all looks good then the problem is server-side though I can't see any obvious problems in the code provided

Hi, Please check the Content-Type it sends to the server, for that please add temporarily the statement  console.log(Content type: ${req.get('Content-Type')}); as the first line in post submit handler.

The problem is with JavaScript checkAnswer function: it sets every option to disabled, and disabled options don't send values when form is submitted, which is why you get empty object on the server.
So, you need to change your logic, and prevent having disabled option which should send data.
For example, you could disable options that are not correct and not checked, and to the correct one add a function which will prevent selecting it afterwards, and by that enable it being submitted along with the form, however, it would not be styled as disabled, but you could style it to appear as disabled, for example, reduce opacity, remove pointer events or similar.
Try this code:
  if (option.value === correctAnswer) {
    label.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    // leave it enabled, but prevent later selections
    option.onclick = () => false;
    // style it a bit to look like disabled
    option.style.opacity = ".5";
    option.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  } else {
    // disabled wrong and unchecked
    option.disabled = true;
    // style wrong
    if (option.checked) label.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

